# Rewrite pipe character to %7C in nginx rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I need to rewrite the pipe character to %7C, my request url looks

```
/foo/stuff.json?fields=id,name|rename(name),stuff[id,name|rename(name),startValue,endValue,color]&paging=false&_dc=12345
```

I'm trying

```
  location /foo {
    rewrite ^(.*)\|(.*)$ $1%7C$2;
  }
```

but that isn't working, any ideas?

Comment: The rewrite rule has %c7, not %7c

Comment: `rewrite` in nginx uses the URI not the query string. You'd need to use `$args` or `$request_uri` to work with the pipe character in the query string.